# Highlight searched text in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am studying React and after implementing the filter functionality I got to think about how to highlight the matched word inside the searched string.

My App.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListValues from './ListValues';

class App extends Component {
  state = { 
    list: ['First string 1', 'second String 2', 'third string 3', 'teste rwe'],
    value: ''
   }

  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div>
        <input 
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })} 
        />
        <ListValues list={this.state.list} value={this.state.value}/>
      </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my ListValues.js file is:

```
import React from 'react';

const ListValues = (props) => {
    return ( 
        <div>
          <ul>
              {props.list.filter(name => {
                return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.value.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
              }).map((value, i) => {
                return <li key={i}>{value}</li>
              })}
          </ul>
        </div>
     );
}

export default ListValues;
```

The index.js file is the standard code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing the point here, you could use styled components to conditionally apply styling (background colour) based on the value of props that you pass into your component.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const ListValue = styled.li`
  ${({ active }) => active && `
    background: blue;
  `}
`;

const ListValues = (props) => {
    return ( 
        <div>
          <ul>
              {props.list.filter(name => {
                return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.value.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
              }).map((value, i) => {
                return <ListValue active={true} key={i}>{value}</ListValue>
              })}
          </ul>
        </div>
     );
}
```

https://www.styled-components.com/docs

Comment: I got this error: 
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/home/checkstore/node_modules/styled-components/dist'

Comment: did you `npm install styled-components --save` ?

Comment: Great, that worked! But is that somehow possible to only highlight the searched word? (I know that I said the wrong intentions in the question before edit it)

Comment: You could potentially split the original string into an array, and map over them in a similar fashion to my example, but instead of a ListValue component you could use a `<Word>` component

Comment: That's great! glad to be of assistance :D

Answer (score 2):

I found a ready-made component for the requirement. If you want customization, please go through the source code and tweak as per your needs.

[react-highlight-words](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words)

Comment: That's great, dude! Exactly what I was doing.