# textarea component with highlighted text in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for some good practice example to change color of text in a textarea in react js

i saw some example with adding div on top of textarea but how to do that in a react way

Comment: Are you just looking to set the text color of the text in the textarea? or are you looking to change it dynamically?

Comment: @shmili : dynamically

Comment: Based on what do you want to style the color?

Comment: I have like 200 words and each text entry is in the new line and its like validating text in textarea in case of any validation error I want to color the text in the textarea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63918430/3767348 this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the text, we need to add html and css. We can't add that in textarea as textarea only contains text, but not html elements.

So, for your usecase, what you gonna do is use a div with contenteditable instead of textarea to enter the text. Like this

```
<div contentEditable></div>
```

Now to do in react way. We need to store the state which will be rendered in div. And upon some action like selection of the text, you can insert the text wrapped around a p tag with style of text color.

For suppose, lets assume this line, `This is a sentence for demo`. When user selects on `sentence`, we can wrap the text with p and update the state like this - `This is a <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>sentence</p> for demo`.

```
const [state, setState] = useState('');

render (
  <div contentEditable>{state}</div>
);
```

Comment: How to add p tag on some action? i want to change text color of say n words for eg 10 words

Comment: with contenteditable there is too much of a handling required. For eg, on paste from excel you have position cursor at the of the string etc. Cant we do this over text area so that extra handling can be avoided?

Comment: If you check my answer again, I already specified that we can't color the text in textarea. The only way you have is to do in html contenteditable. Check this similar answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160584/10616955, he said the same.

Comment: For reference, you can check this - https://codesandbox.io/s/godzilla-editor-up2se. I was playing around with text editor in some way. I will try with contenteditable and comment here.